# Why does enabling @jwt_required on all my routes cause an assertion error in Flask's __init__.py?

Tags: authentication, flask, jwt, blueprint, flask-jwt-extended

[image]

When I enable `@jwt_required` on all my routes in users.py, running `__init__.py` fails and shows assertion error. If I enable `@jwt_required` only on 1 of the routes (doesn't matter which one), the flask app succeeds in building. This is for a flask-react app.

```
from flask import Blueprint, request
from flask_jwt_extended import jwt_required

users = Blueprint('users', __name__)

@users.route('/profile', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def profile():
    return "<p>Profile</p>"

@users.route('/settings', methods=["PUT"])
@jwt_required
def settings():
    return "<p>Settings</p>"
```

Answer (score 0):

where is the call to `create_access_token`? have you seen the [examples](https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/tree/master/examples) for the lib yet? Your app hasn't shown much about the usage yet, where are tokens coming from, how are they generated, etc.

You probably should just take a working example from the lib docs, and if you can't get the official working example, working, create a issue on the lib repo.

Bet to ask a SO question when you have specific things, than basic getting started that are more appropriate for the lib repo. If that fails ask here and show what you tried yourself to help solve the issue before asking SO.

Answer (score 0):

add the endpoint parameter ( endpoint='<func_name>') to route annotation. It worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).